# Is there a way to generate constants with Reinforced.Typings?

Tags: reinforced-typings

I have a big C# class with a lot of `const` fields in it. Is there a way to include the values of these consts when generating ts types with Reinforced.Typings?
I have read the documentation up and down several times, but I haven't been able to find an answer there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properties cannot be constant in C#. Do you mean `const` fields?

In this case you can use fluent configuration like `.ExportAsClass<...>().WithPublicFields()`.

Comment: Yes, I mean ```const``` fields, edited my question to fix the terminology. I've looked at ```WithPublicFields()```, but the generated class only includes type information for these fields, they are not initialized with values. ```InitializeWith()``` doesn't do anything, I've tried with and without it. I've been looking at this test: https://github.com/reinforced/Reinforced.Typings/blob/master/Reinforced.Typings.Tests/SpecificCases/SpecificTestCases.ConstantProperties.cs but I still don't get any values. I'm using Reinforced.Typings v1.5.9

Comment: Ugh. I had ```.ExportPureTypings()``` in the global config. Removed it, works perfectly now. Thanks for your help